# Connection problems in hosted Blazor Webassembly with SignalR

Tags: c#, websocket, blazor, signalr

**Summary**

I am working on a microservices project with several client access (mvc asp.net web application, hosted blazor webassembly, etc.) all in a kubernetes cluster. Recently I updated all applications to .NET 7 but I don't know if this is the reason for my problems.

**Symptoms**

In the Blazor Webassembly (Hosted) PWA I am using SignalR Hub for the communication between the Blazor.Client and Blazor.Server. When I call a page, then immediately go back before the page has been loaded completely, I get web socket errors. On the other hand the app is extremely slow.

**Errors**

*Unhandled exception rendering component: **Cannot access a disposed object.**
Object name: 'HubConnection'.
System.ObjectDisposedException....in HubConnection.SendCoreAsync...*

*Unhandled exception rendering component: The 'SendCoreAsync' method cannot be called if the **connection is not active**.
System.InvalidOperationException....in ReconnectingConnectionState.WaitForActiveConnectionAsync...*

**Trying workarounds**

I am trying to catch these exceptions because I couldn't find a reason or a solution (extension method CallAsync):

```
if ( hubConnection is not null )
{
    try
    {    
        await hubConnection.SendAsync( methodName, arg1, arg2, cancellationToken );
    }
    catch ( ObjectDisposedException ) { }
    catch ( InvalidOperationException ) { }
}
```

But I still get the error message "**The operation was canceled**".

**More code**

Creating the hub connection in a method (client):

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl( Navigator.ToAbsoluteUri( hubPath ), options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult( ((AuthStateProvider)AuthStateProv).Token );
        // added the next lines later to try out
        options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        options.SkipNegotiation = true;
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
```

Using the hub connection (client):

```
// this is the method above passing the hubPath
hubConnection = CreateHubConnection( "/testhub" );
hubConnection.On<MyDataModel>( "ReceiveData", ( result ) => HandleData( result ) );
await hubConnection.StartAsync();
// calling method (first code above)
await CallAsync( hubConnection, "RequestData" );
```

Disposing the HubConnection in the razor component:

```
public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if ( hubConnection is not null )
    {
        try
        {
            await hubConnection.StopAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The Hub (server):

```
public class TestHub : BaseHub
{
    public async Task RequestData()
    {
        // get data from a microservice api
        var result = await _getQuery.Get();

        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync( "ReceiveData", result );
    }
}
```

Blazor.Server startup configuration (Program.cs):

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR( options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 );
    options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 30 );
    options.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 3;
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
} );
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression( opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" } );
} );

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.MapHub<TestHub>( "/testhub" );
```

First I am getting this message in the browser:
*WARNING: Web browsers do not support closing the output side of a WebSocket. CloseOutputAsync has closed the socket and discarded any incoming messages.*

Comment: We need to find out if the connection every completed.  Di you get back a response with a status code?  Status code is normally 200 OK, and a 400/500 if there is an error.  If you do not get back a response the HTTPS (Secure) failed.  HTTPS uses TLS to establish an encryption key.  TLS is sent before the request and if TLS fails the request is never sent and you do not get back a response.  Blazor would give back a response if TLS succeeds and the error code would indicate if the credentials failed.

Comment: @jdweng I get 200 OK. The app is working normally when I am letting it loading the pages but when I don't wait and cancel the loading/going back immediately, these exceptions occur.

Comment: Add an exception handler to catch the exception.  you can't stop the server from sending the data.  You are breaking the connection to stop the loading and causing the exception.  Best solution is to add a try/catch to stop the error message from occurring.

Comment: I am trying to simulate a normal user behaviour when going back immediately. Where should I add the try/catch?

Comment: I think the .WithAutomaticReconnect() is causing the issue.  I would think the exception is while the await is occurring on followng line : await CallAsync( hubConnection, "RequestData" );

Answer (score 1):

After intensive debugging I could localize the exceptions.

When the user go back while the page is loading first af all DisposeAsync in the razor page is called and the hubConnection is disposed but not null, then OnInitializedAsync is called, where the hubConnection is created and started. I am also calling a method after starting the hubConnection. So the first Exception is thrown when starting the hubConnection: OperationCanceledException in StartAsync. The second Exception is thrown when calling the hub method: ObjectDisposedException. So at these two locations I need to add try/catches as jdweng noticed.

In the method call I already had the try/catch (see first code in question). I just added another one to the StartAsync:

```
try
{
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
catch ( OperationCanceledException ) { }
```

btw hubConnection.StopAsync is not needed because hubConnection.DisposeAsync is stopping the hubConnection. The HubConnection SendCoreAsyncCore method is checking first whether it is disposed or not and throwing the Exception and after 100 calls it is checking the CancellationToken with the comment "Bail early for cancellation".